# De-envelope using bouncycastle's java libararies

Tags: java, encryption, bouncycastle, smime

I have a DER file which was created by openssl smime.

I would like to extract ciphertext from the encrypted SMIME file and the certificates.

I have the code in Python which does as follows:

```
decode(BytesFromDer, asn1Spec=rfc2315.ContentInfo())
```

decode is the function from from pyasn1.codec.der.decoder import decode
and BytesFromDer is bytes array of the content in the DER file.

and then

```
decode(content['content'], asn1Spec=rfc2315.EnvelopedData())
```

as decode is from from pyasn1.codec.der.decoder import decode
and content is the content we got in the last decode.

But I can't find a similar function to decode by rfc2315 (which is pkcs7) in Java.
Does anyone know if Java has something for un-enveloping?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Yes, in general, I did used ASN1StreamParser object from bouncycastle and processed it with some other ASN1 objects from that library.